# Running docker containers as Jenkins Slave

Tags: docker, jenkins, dockerfile

I have Jenkins installed on my system and I want to run docker containers as Jenkins slave.

I am confused with the configuration part of jenkins after installing docker plugin.

What should  I enter in those settings?

Answer (score 1):

> You'll need to edit Jenkins system configuration (Jenkins > Manage > System configuration) and add a new Cloud of type "Docker"

That means you need to have docker installed in a cloud (a local one like VirtualBox, or a remote one, like Amanzon EC2.

See for instance "[Using Docker as a Jenkins Cloud Provider](https://www.nuxeo.com/blog/docker-jenkins-cloud-provider/)".